# Where can I ask about consumption of iron?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I'm wondering where to ask about the consumption of iron  and Daily Value.

My question:

> If 150% RDV (Recommend Daily Value) of iron is consumed in a day, from foods, is that bad?

Comment: What type question do you want to ask?

Comment: I added my question, does that help?

Comment: I think I’m misunderstanding. You’re asking if it’s bad to eat 100% of the recommended daily value of Iron in one day?

Comment: The answers are very helpful. I would start with Medical Sciences if it's as straightforward as it is here. But do  not identify yourself as a patient on any site, or your question will be closed. Ask generically  and state information you wish to know, for example, if the RDV dose  is too high, just ask that.

Comment: @divibisan I meant 150%, but based on what I wrote before you're correct.

Comment: Just as a comment to the acual matter at hand - It would not be bad. the RDV is meant as a guideline for how much you need over time, every day. If any ill effect was even close to that intake, there would not be a recommendation for it. But do avoid 150% every day.

Comment: @jj-for-transparency-and-monica It is very generalized because all (proper) RDV **are** generalized. 150% of any rdv for 1 day should always be OK. Consider the mean value theorem. If eating 50% for 1 day is OK, then 150% the next day has to be, or else there is no RDV. Now, if the RDV was not from an official institution, why even ask, it is then not an RDV because it is not Recommended by any authority. Rdvs are not minimum lethal dosages.

Comment: @jj-for-transparency-and-monica It is very generalized because all (proper) RDV **are** generalized. 150% of any rdv for 1 day should always be OK. Consider the mean value theorem. If eating 50% for 1 day is OK, then 150% the next day has to be, or else there is no RDV. Now, if the RDV was not from an official institution, why even ask, it is then not an RDV because it is not Recommended by any authority. Rdvs are not minimum lethal dosages.

Comment: Why not just ask your doctor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### It’s going to depend on what kind of question you’re asking and why

If you’re asking about this in terms of exercise or fitness, then [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) might be a good option. The help section says that it is on-topic to ask about:

> - nutrition as it relates to exercise

But the following topics are off-topic:

> - nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc.
> - wellness, general health, medical advice and injuries unrelated to exercise

---

If you’re a Vegan or Vegetarian and are worried about getting enough Iron, then you could ask on [Veganism & Vegetarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com) which says that topics related to:

> - How to stay healthy living while living a veg*n.

Are on-topic

---

Personal nutrition is generally **off-topic** on Biology and Medical Sciences:

**Biology:**

> Which questions are off-topic?
>
> - personal medical questions and health advice

**Medical Sciences:**

> Often asked questions that are off-topic include:
>
> - medical advice for yourself or others
> - questions about nutrition and diet that aren't directly connected to medical treatment

If you were asking about the *biology* of iron usage, then Biology might be a good option. Similarly, if your question about iron is directly related to  understanding a medical treatment (but is **not** a request for medical advice), you might be able to ask it on Medical Sciences. If you go with either of those options, though, you should be very clear about how your question is about science, not personal medical or nutritional advice.

---

**Skeptics:**

If you're asking about the accuracy of a published claim about Iron (for example, if you read somewhere that eating 100% of your RDV of Iron is actually bad), then you could ask about the truth of that claim on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com). Note that this must be a **notable claim** that has been made publicly, so be sure to have a citation for it:

> Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.
>
> If you have a question about the accuracy of public claims made in the media or elsewhere, if you're interested in the evidence behind what you hear or read, then you are in the right place.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I *hope* I'll have changed it, but suspect I won't.

Comment: @Mari-LouA perhaps Monica will have a court order by then

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica there's also the possibility that SE will have shut down MetaSE, there's too much bad publicity and feeling among its users, it's all concentrated here, on this one site.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want to know/ask about.

If you want to ask about the effect of consumption of iron on your body, [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) site is probably the best choice, and it already has [iron tag](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron).

Otherwise, not sure SE contains a fitting site, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I added my question, does that help?

Comment: Although this answer is accepted, the [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337602/401068) is probably better guidance. Importantly, it describes the prohibition against nutrition and personal health advice on Medical Sciences (which is a consistent source of Bad Questions on that site), and the similar prohibition on Biology.SE.

Comment: Yes. I agree I want to accept both.

Comment: @GBikeZ8 I agree the other answer is better.